# Issue with videoview on Android 2.1

Tags: android

i am trying to play a video via streaming in my android application. Video playing functionality works good but whenever changes the orientation of the phone...a white screen comes over the video view and audio keeps playing. And after turning back to original orientation, video starts playing normally..(with proper video and audio.).

Please help.. what should i do??

thanks...

Comment: Which 2.1 devices are you seeing this on?

Comment: i have tested mainly on Google nexus

Answer (score 1):

You may want to lock your activity into a single orientation (i.e. landscape). If not, I'd suggest creating your own `MediaPlayer` instead of using `VideoView`, and persisting the `MediaPlayer` object across configuration changes using [`onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()). Note that you might have to do some teardown and setup of the media playback output surface in this case.

Comment: Roman, i am facing this issue only on Android 2.1 devices.. but when i run my code on G1, hero(which are 1.5 devices), it works perfectly well, no white screen on orientation change..nothing everything works perfect.